# How to find the processing time of Kafka messages?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an application running Kafka consumers and want to monitor the processing time of each message consumed from the topic. The application is a Spring boot application and exposes Kafka consumer metrics to Spring Actuator Prometheus endpoint using micrometre registry.
Can I use kafka_consumer_commit_latency_avg_seconds or kafka_consumer_commit_latency_max_seconds to monitor or alert?

Answer (score 2):

Those metrics have nothing to do with record processing time. spring-kafka provides metrics for that; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#monitoring-listener-performance).

> **Monitoring Listener Performance**

> Starting with version 2.3, the listener container will automatically create and update Micrometer Timer s for the listener, if Micrometer is detected on the class path, and a single MeterRegistry is present in the application context. The timers can be disabled by setting the ContainerProperty `micrometerEnabled` to false.

Two timers are maintained - one for successful calls to the listener and one for >failures.

Comment: Very clear answer. Would it be possible to have the same for reactor-kafka project please?

Comment: There's an open issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/206 - contributions are welcome.